# PostgreSQL login works on local host but not xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, database-connection

So I open the psql terminal (on Windows). I log into it with the server set on localhost,

But when I try to log into it with my production host:

```
xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I get the following error:

```
> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "128.6.37.14", user "postgres",
> database "campus", SSL off
```

I tried adding it to the pg_hba.conf, but no luck:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             128.6.37.14/32          trust
```

Any idea what the issue is? Is the host correct? It's what I got when I ran `heroku config`

How do I fix this?

Comment: I hope you restarted the service?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), the Heroku Database as a Service based on PostgreSQL, right?

If so, you can use the heroku pg:psql CLI command to [connect to your Heroku Postgres database from outside of Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku).

First, issue the following command to get your Heroku Postgres Add-on name:

```
heroku pg:info
```

Then you can do:

```
heroku pg:psql <Add-on>
```

e.g.

```
heroku pg:psql postgresql-parallel-XXXXX
```